# How would I make a copy of a linked list using an ADT in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

So I am given the following structs:

```
typedef struct nodeStruct
{
    int data;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
}Node;

typedef struct linkedList
{
    Node *head, *tail;
}List;
```

I have to make to create a function that copies the contents of an existing list into a new one using the given function prototype:

```
List *copyList(List *passedList);
```

How would I go about doing this? It is stomping me.

Edit: If it helps, I have this function to create a null list:

```
List *createList()
{
    List *newList = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));

    if (newList == NULL)
    {
        puts("ERROR: Could not allocate memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    newList->head = newList->tail = NULL;
    return newList;
}
```

Edit x2: I have a createNode function and an insertAtTail (append) function as follows:

```
Node *createNode(int nodeValue) // this function creates a node with the value that is passed to it
{
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode -> data = nodeValue;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int insertAtTail(int nodeValue, List *passedList)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        puts("ERROR: Could not allocate memory.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    newNode -> data = nodeValue;
    newNode -> next = NULL;

    if (passedList->tail == NULL)
    {
        passedList->head = passedList->tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        passedList->tail->next = newNode;
        passedList->tail = newNode;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would assume you traverse the list to copy and build up a copy of the list on the way.

Comment: @Thomas I am not quite sure how I would do that though with the linkedList struct. If it was just the nodeStruct that would be a lot more simple but this makes it a bit harder for me to understand.

Comment: Do you have a function to add an element to the end of a list?  If not, write one?  Then as you step through the old list, you use the function to add a copy of the current node in the old list to the tail of the new list.  Ideally, you have a function that 'applies' a function to each element of the list, but that's for the future — for now, write the code to copy a list more or less as outlined.

Comment: `"So I am given the following structs:"` -- thank your professor for knowing what he is doing. In your function, simply declare a new pointer to represent your copied list, then iterate over your current list, calling an `add` node function to add each node in your current list to the copy, see `add()` in , e.g. [Singly Linked List of Integers](https://pastebin.com/CsBYkjrq). Then just return the pointer to the copy.

Comment: Another thought is since your `list` (wrapper) contains only the `head/tail` pointers, you don't really need to allocate for the list. Just change your return type to `List` and declare your copy with *automatic storage duration* and return the struct (saves an allocation and free of the `List` -- all you have to worry about freeing are the `Node` nodes in the list)

Comment: Nit... In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Better to use the dereferenced pointer to set *type-size*, e.g. `Node *newNode = malloc( sizeof *newNode);` On error use `perror ("malloc-newNode");` instead of `puts(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break this down into tasks:

1. Create a new node.
2. Iterate through old list.
3. Add node to the new list.

So make a function called `createNode()` which returns to the caller a new node just like `createList()` does.

Then make a function called `appendList()` (or whatever name you like) which adds a single node to the end of a linked list. This function should use `createNode()` to make the new node. It should also be able to handle adding a node to an empty linked list as well.

Then inside `copyList()`, create a new list (the one you will be copying values into), iterate over the old linked list and call your `appendList()` function to put the node value into the new list. Then return a pointer to the new list.

Comment: I have updated my post with my `createNode` and `insertAtTail` function. Now that that is done, I just need help laying out the proper code for the function. How would I iterate through the old list using the ADT? That is the one thing I am struggling with.

Comment: You can use a while loop to test if the current iterating pointer is not null, and while that is true you can append the node value to the new list and go to its next node. You start from the head pointer of the passed list.